# A calc() value within a calc() value

Tags: css, calc

Suppose, I am creating an image gallery; at a certain device width, there will be three images, hence, I need to work out one third:

```
{width:calc(100% / 3)}
```

However, the issue is that I need to take away '2px' (two pixels) - I added a margin of 1px, hence this needs to be accounted for by taking this away from the width, hence I need to do:

```
{width:calc(calc(100% / 3) - 2px)}
```

But, this does not work: is there a way I can do this?

[I need to work out a third, then take two pixels away from this -- it is messy because a third is difficult to format as a percentage.]

Comment: have you tried `calc(100% / 3 - 2px)` without the additional `calc()` ? In this case I would assume that the division takes precedence anyway ? Could you try that ?

Comment: Yes, operator precedence is respected, see [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). If you wish to be explicit you can use `calc((100% / 3) - 2px)`

Comment: I am not sure that it works, I am trying to this: `@media screen and (min-width:1000px){.g li {width:calc(100% / 3 -2px)}}`

Comment: @Sk9TSFVBQkVBTA `+` and `-` operators **must** be surrounded by whitespaces

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think you need to have spaces between operators and operands. So make sure you have a space in there like so: `@media screen and (min-width:1000px){.g li {width:calc(100% / 3 - 2px)}}`

Comment: @AndreaGhidini, thank you, it has worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I will add an answer here (The solution has already been posted in the comments underneath the asker's question).

You don't need to use two `calc()` statements. It's sufficient for you to combine the calculations within one `calc()` statement. In this case, as Andrea Ghidini mentioned in a comment (refer to [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)), the division will take precedence over the subtraction (basic math rules apply!).

So your solution would be:

```
width:calc(100% / 3 - 2px)
```

**Also, make sure that additions and subtractions are surrounded by whitespaces, otherwise it will not work!**

Comment: Good, I was in the middle of writing an answer myself :)

Comment: @AndreaGhidini I would gladly share my rep with you if I could! I will upvote one or two of your answers (that I personally find useful) to make up for that! :)

Comment: not a problem, here the goal is to help each other! :)

Comment: @AndreaGhidini Yes, let's not forget about that!